# SQL sum and group by week

Tags: sql

I need to follow how much money customers owes me. Need to have weekly report.

I take one invoice as example (invoice nr - INV001). I sent invoice on 2020 09 11 (week 37) and received money on 2020 09 28.

I create a code

```
Select
Datepart(Week, [Posting Date]) as week,
[Cust_NR],
Sum ([Amount]) as Amount
from
TABLE
Where [CUST_NR] = '623772' 
Group by
Datepart(Week, [Posting Date]),
[Cust_NR]
```

Output is simple:
week 37 - Amount 1000 EUR (sent invoice on this week), and week 40 - Amount -1000 EUR (received the money)

It is not what I want.

It should be:

```
week 37 - 1000 EUR (sent an invoice)
week 38 - 1000 EUR (money is not received, amount is open)
week 39 - 1000 EUR (money is not received, amount is open)
week 40 - 0 EUR (money is received in this week and customer owes me nothing)
```

any tips what should i do? it also enough if someone provides me what to google, because i have no idea.

Thanks

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) How are you defining weeks?

Comment: The 'missing' weeks are likely not in your table, because there was no action. And you can't select what isn't there. I suggest you search for `calendar table` (plus your dbms, looks like sql server), you'll find many examples and tutorials